# Did I really just get my CV for only $9?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

OK this makes no sense but I just got my CV for $9 (USD). Is this a new special? Is this any different from the $19 one?

Also if this is a secret then I'm sorry!

Comment: sounds like spam, but probably isn't - I got the same offer, because I'm an *avid* user. Probably means someone with *no life outside SO*

Comment: @pavium: Having no life outside of SO is a bad thing? But I like waffles and free-hand circles.

Comment: Waffles? They have waffles?

Comment: @pavium: Dude no one told you? Your really missing out. What did you think the $9 (or $19) was for?

Comment: I'm missing out because I live in a remote corner of the world.

Comment: They've sent all people spending more than 8 hours/day on SO such an offer because evidentially, they don't have a job. (How else could they afford so much SO time?)

Comment: @gs: OMG I spend more than 8 hours a day on SO? This can't be healthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal -- we plan to make periodic special CV filing offers available, for new CV filers and "special friends of Stack Overflow".

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-lower-careers-pricing/

> We plan to keep improving and refining the careers service throughout the year. **Specifically, we’ll be exploring other options to reduce barriers to filing CVs**, as well as publishing broad statistics about employer searches.

Comment: **I didn't think to check the blog?** I'm an idiot. BTW you have been updating that thing like crazy!

Comment: Who are these "special friends of Stack Overflow"? Except @rockhardawesome of course... :)

Comment: I for one appreciate it. Seeing as how I'm not currently in the market, I hadn't even really given Careers much thought. I got that e-mail last night and thought, for about the price of a good cigar, I can get a year of Careers searchability should the need arise -- that's pretty much a no-brainer! (I'll be joining up this week.)

Comment: so, if i may ask, what was the criteria for "avid users"? yearlings? certain rep? enthusiasts/fanatics? first page user on one of the sites? i got the e-mail about the reduced price but i'm not sure why...

Comment: @Kip - me too - with less than 2,000 rep on SO! I visit Meta every day, so maybe it's included?

Comment: yeah, but so what - really, SO is a site that is made by your contributors - if we all disappeared, you'd have nothing. And you reward us by asking us to pay to use a new feature of the site? Really, you need to be asking members to upload freely, and charging employers to view or contact them. $9 isn't very much, but I don't even get to see how many employers are looking, its not as well thought out as the original site design.